# How to get date in php

Tags: php

I'm setting up a new server, and want to support sending date of users to the database but I can't know what the error in my code

```
    <input type="hidden" name="created" id="created" value="<?php string date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>"/>
```

know this is the code that works:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="created" id="created" value="<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>"/>
```

Comment: remove the `string` text. It's a syntax error. BTW you should learn about how to see and fix errors in PHP, and any other language.

Comment: it's don't work

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: You need to echo or print the date to make it show up in the markup. Example: `<?php echo date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>`

Comment: no data (time) !

Comment: It's working now thx

Comment: For the next time, if you assume that there is an error, share any existing error messages or any context about that error